# How to test javascript function independently with mocha chai and sinon?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I am new to unit testing and have been reading a few tutorials about this practice with javascript. I will use a silly example to explain my problem.

Let's say John needs to go to school and before knowing if he's ready to go he has to check if he has his bag and his headphones. This would be called with the following function:

```
john.isReadyToGo;
```

The implementation of the isReadtToGo() function for a character object is as follows:

```
characher.isReadyToGo = function() {
    return this.hasBag() && this.hasHeadPhones();
}

characher.hasBag = function() {
    // return true or false
}

characher.hasHeadPhones = function() {
    //return true or false
}
```

Now, let's say I want to test this function. In unit testing it is recommended to test functions without them being affected by other functions. This means that in this case I would have to test the three functions but the character.isReadyToGo() function would need to have mock values for this.hasBag() and this.hasHeadPhones(). Am I right?

If so, could you give me a hint on how I can mock these two values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
let character = {};

character.isReadyToGo = function() {
    return this.hasBag() && this.hasHeadPhones();
}

character.hasBag = function() {
    // return true or false
}

character.hasHeadPhones = function() {
    //return true or false
}

const sinon  = require('sinon');
const expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('Is character ready?', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    sinon.stub(character, 'hasBag');
    sinon.stub(character, 'hasHeadPhones');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    character.hasBag.restore();
    character.hasHeadPhones.restore();
  });

  it("Not if they don't have a bag or headphones", () => {
    character.hasBag.returns(false);
    character.hasHeadPhones.returns(false);
    expect(character.isReadyToGo()).to.be.false;
  });

  it("Not if they have headphones but no bag", () => {
    character.hasBag.returns(false);
    character.hasHeadPhones.returns(true);
    expect(character.isReadyToGo()).to.be.false;
  });

  it("Not if they have a bag but no headphones", () => {
    character.hasBag.returns(true);
    character.hasHeadPhones.returns(false);
    expect(character.isReadyToGo()).to.be.false;
  });

  it("Yes, if they have a bag and headphones", () => {
    character.hasBag.returns(true);
    character.hasHeadPhones.returns(true);
    expect(character.isReadyToGo()).to.be.true;
  });

});
```

For each test, this stubs `character.hasBag` and `character.hadHeadphones` (this is done in `beforeEach`). This basically replaces the original with a new function (the stub) that you can control.

Depending on the test, the stub is "told" what to return for each function (using `.returns()`), `isReadyToGo` is called, and its result is checked against the expectation.

After each test, the stub is restored (meaning that the original function is restored).

Comment: Minor detail - shouldn't those be `.to.be.true();` instead of `.to.be.true;`?